# Package deployed in SSIS 2012 catalog fails with timeout error

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I created an SSIS package in Visual Studio 2008 and deployed it to SQL Server 2012 by using Integration Services Catalogs. When I run the package from BIDS it completes successfully. When I schedule the package to run using a job the execution of the job fails (sometime randomly) with the following message:

> Environment reference Id: NULL. Description: Timeout expired. The
>   timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the
>   server is not responding. Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider

I tried to add retry for this step and at second retry it works fine. I don't know the reason,  this job worked for 2 years with no issues.

Comment: Do you running this ssis package in BIDS on same box when you have it scheduled as sql job ? Do you using same sql account for sql agent and when you running package manually ?

Comment: the problem is :the same scheduled job fail somtime(not always).. randomly diffrent behavior with same Box..

Comment: So... maybe it is network issue not your etl issue.

Comment: the ssiscatalog db and sql agent job which executes ssis Package are on the Same Machine.

Comment: the other people encounter same problem sugest to Alter Builtin SP in ssicatalog db. anyone have idea about suggestion in this :[http://speaksql.wordpress.com/2013/06/27/ssis-2012-fail-to-start-execution-timed-out/]

Comment: this link is Error 404 - Not Found

Comment: sorry it is ok just need to remove end ] Did you tried to apply indexes mentioned in this article http://www.ssistalk.com/2013/01/31/ssis-2012-catalog-indexing-recommendations/ ? Think it was solved by CU4 or higher https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/803880/integration-services-catalog-ssisdb-database-indexes-for-ssis-server-maintenance-job

Comment: i add the index mentioed. and i will inform you if it does not retry or fail after 5 days Of Execution (beacaues it is nighly job and failed somtime)

Comment: adding index not work for me. and again last night job was go to retry and after retry it works.strangely is always one step(Analysis services Processing Step Which is after ETL step) was go to retry

Comment: i found that in my ssis Package there is a child package refrence that is disable and the references child package does not exist anymore.i delete Disable child package reference and i delete the package from SSIScatalog and rebuild and redeploy the package .and my problem is gone . i found that any connections that is invalid (even if we does not use them). may cause this problem.

Comment: good to hear that you are ok ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete Unused Connection String(specially those have invalid connection string) search for child Package reference that are disable but has invalid references.